# SSH Private Key Authentication Fails When Using a Exported Vagrant Box Imported into VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using an exported Vagrant box. The file extension is .ova. 
I import it into the VirtualBox and place its id into the "id" file in "/home/user/Documents/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default" folder. After this I run "vagrant up" command. I get the following output

**Debug output**

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3001 (guest) => 3003 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3000 (guest) => 9090 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 (guest) => 9091 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8161 (guest) => 8166 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

SSH times out, although authentication fails, I am still able to SSH into my machine using "vagrant ssh" but the sync folders that I have defined in the vagrant file are not created.

I am using:

**Vagrant version:** Vagrant 1.8.1

**VirtualBox version:** Version 5.0.40

**Host operating system:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**Guest operating system:** CentOS 7.0

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "oneops"

 # Use the vagrant-cachier plugin, if installed, to cache downloaded packages
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3003
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 9090
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 9091
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8161, host: 8166

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.gui = false
   vb.memory = 6144
   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "70"]
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/Share/", "/home/vagrant/Documents/Share/"
end
```

**End Result:** I am unable to create sync folders between my host and guest machine. When I try to halt the machine using "vagrant halt" I get the following output

```
$ vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    default: capable.
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
```

Can anyone help me figure out what might be the issue here?